# Why should we call TrimToSize method of a Queue?

Tags: c#, queue

> The capacity of a Queue is the number of elements the Queue can hold. As elements are added to a Queue, the capacity is automatically increased as required through reallocation. The capacity can be decreased by calling TrimToSize.

This is written in [MSDN Queue Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx)

Now the question is that in a queue if we add around 20 thousand items then one by one that queue is De-queued until the queue is empty. If we don't call TrimToSize function then the queue size will remain to that 20 Thousand but the data is removed by the garbage collector so technically there is no memory leak and if we check the count or serialize the queue the size is of an empty queue. **So why should we call TrimToSize function ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the GC of the objects in the queue with the "slots" of memory for the queue itself.

The queue will have allocated space to store all the 20K references.... those slots will just be empty, and therefore not pointing to objects which are taking up yet more memory. But those "slots" will sstill be there, waiting to have references assigned to them.

Answer (score 1):

Think in terms of the two sets of objects:

```
queue       other things
+------+
| slot | -> item
| slot | -> item
| slot | -> item
:      :
| slot | -> item
+------+
```

While the items themselves may be garbage-collected when no longer used, that doesn't affect the *single* object, the queue, which is still in use.

However, it may have been expanded to a gazillion slots at some point when your load was high and it will keep that size until told otherwise.

By calling `TrimToSize` on the queue, you reduce the number of *slots* in use, potentially releasing memory back to the free pool for other purposes.

The queue can get quite large even *without* adding a lot of elements since you can configure the high multiplier for it (the value that its capacity is multiplied by when you add to a full queue).

It's all just good memory management, often used for queues where you know they won't increase in size again.

A classic example of this is reading in configuration items from a file. Once you've read them in, it's unlikely they'll increase in size again (until you re-read the file, which would usually be infrequent).

If your queue is likely to change size frequently, up and down all over the place, you may be better off *not* using `TrimToSize`.

Answer (score 1):

Assume if queue stores items in an internal array, and when capacity is increases, a new array is allocated and and items are moved from old smaller size array to this new array.

Assuming initial capacity is 16, so array of length 16 is allocated in memory. Now your array is grown to 20000, probably due to spike in algorithm and once all jobs are processed and queue contains only 1 item. This time you are using array with 20000 length. In this case your queue is occupying way too much memory then needed.

Queue will mostly used for long running, task management kind of algorithm in which memory usage will be very dynamic. Reducing capacity will help in better performance as if you have many instances and each will outgrow, you will have most of memory unused.

Looking at this scenario I will prefer to use linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

The capacity is not increased one by one. If I remember correctly the capacity is being doubled each time the size reaches the threshold. TrimToSize sets the capacity to exactly the size.

Usually you won't need to call that Method. But there can be situations when you want to marshal or serialize.

It is also very true what Andrew sais.

Answer (score 0):

Queue use object[] for hold elements, so even you dequeue all elements you will have array with length 20000 in the memory